# How can I reduce the wind noise as much as possible when recording a video with a GoPro?

Tags: microphone, gopro

I use a GoPro 10 to record videos. The GoPro is placed on a car. There's some pretty audible wind noise, esp. when the speed is over 50 or 100 kph. How can I reduce the wind noise as much as possible when recording a video with a GoPro?

I've turned the wind noise removal on on the GoPro settings. tried using the [official GoPro protection case](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B08FRTLX2M) and some "[windscreen windslayer cover housing frame case](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B09JMWZ28Y)", it helps but there's still some wind noise. What else can I do?

I'm aware of [How to reduce wind noise from a video?](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/8468/2117) but that's for post-processing the wind noise.

---

[Official GoPro protection case](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B08FRTLX2M):

[image]

[Windscreen windslayer cover housing frame case](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B09JMWZ28Y):

[image]

Comment: Is the GoPro mounted externally? What sounds are you trying to capture? One solutions would be a separate mic, closer to your subject - inside the car, in the engine bay etc.

Comment: @Tetsujin externally mounted indeed. I'm trying to capture the ambient sounds and don't wish to record anyone inside the car. Where could be a good place to place an additional mic and what type of microphones has a good sound quality at 100+ kph? Thanks!

Comment: I think you may need an external solution, mic in a 'zeppelin' blimp covered by a 'dead cat' secondary windshield. That's de rigueur for outdoor filming, but idk whether it's good enough for a moving vehicle - that's outside my experience.

Answer (score 0):

As [Tetsujin](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/12233/tetsujin) [mentioned](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/35547/how-can-i-reduce-the-wind-noise-as-much-as-possible-when-recording-a-video-with#comment46036_35547) in the comment, a typical solution is to use an external microphone with a wind shield (aka windscreen or dead cat). One may get a [GoPro Pro 3.5mm Mic Adapter](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01L2CPPH2) to connect an external microphone to the GoPro.

Here are the microphone suggestions I've read online:

- [Olympus ME-51S Stereo Microphone](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B000BTAH62/) ([source 1](http://www.dragtimes.com/blog/how-to-record-great-exhaust-sound-videos-and-clips-using-a-gopro-and-external-microphone), [source 2](https://youtu.be/IUZ6NdNcyw4), [demo](https://youtu.be/jeyhEXLx9iA))
- [Rode VideoMicro Ultracompact Camera-Mount Shotgun Microphone](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B015R0IQGW) ([source](https://youtu.be/nU6z9vu7iTI), [demo](https://youtu.be/nU6z9vu7iTI?t=1)) + Rode WS9 Deluxe Wind Shield for VideoMicro + Manfrotto 035RL Super Clamp with Standard Stud + Tape King Gaffers Tape.
- [Lavalier Lapel Microphone](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B08XQBPJN5) ([source](https://youtu.be/ujYxDr771Ww), [demo](https://youtu.be/ujYxDr771Ww?t=613))

Pictures of setup from [dragtimes.com](http://www.dragtimes.com/blog/how-to-record-great-exhaust-sound-videos-and-clips-using-a-gopro-and-external-microphone):

[image]

[image]

Another picture of setup ([source](https://youtu.be/ujYxDr771Ww?t=707)):

[image]

A more advanced setup: